# com.adobe.acrobat.jpeg EL servidor remoto no existe o no está disponible

Tags: vba, pdf

Gusto en saludar, tengo un inconveniente al intentar guardar un PDF como imagen JPG, he consultado algunas fuentes de las que he obtenido la idea y algo de código, no obstante, al usar `ExportFormat = "com.adobe.acrobat.jpeg"` me sale error de automatización y me dice que el servidor remoto no existe o no está disponible...

¿Alguien quizás me echa una manito para lograr guardar mi PDF como JGP?, adjunto parte de mi código.

```
Function CreateCertify(ByVal dataUser As Object) 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim pdfApp As acrobat.AcroApp '
Dim pdfDoc As acrobat.AcroAVDoc 
Dim SupportDoc As acrobat.AcroPDDoc

Set pdfApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set pdfDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

If pdfDoc.Open(dataUser("FormatDiploma"), "") = True Then
    pdfApp.Hide    
    Set SupportDoc = pdfDoc.GetPDDoc

    '...................................

    ' Aquí guardo el documento luego de unas modificaciones que hago previamente
    If SupportDoc.Save(PDSaveFull, dataUser("UrlToSave")) = True Then
        Dim jsoObject As Object
        Dim ExportFormat As String
        Dim NewFilePath As String
        Dim boResult As Boolean
        
        Set jsoObject = SupportDoc.GetJSObject
        ExportFormat = "com.adobe.acrobat.jpeg"
        
        NewFilePath = Split(dataUser("UrlToSave"), ".pdf")(0) & ".jpg"
        dataUser.Add "UrlImg", NewFilePath
        
        ' AQUI ES DONDE ME PRESENTA EL ERROR
        boResult = jsoObject.SaveAs(NewFilePath, ExportFormat)
        '--------------------------------------------------------
    End If

    pdfDoc.Close True
    SupportDoc.Close    
    Set SupportDoc = Nothing
End If

pdfApp.Exit
Set pdfDoc = Nothing
Set pdfApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Function
```

- ¿Quizás se usa un servidor distinto a día de hoy?
- ¿Quizás existe una manera diferente de realizar lo que necesito?

Agradezco desde ya el apoyo.